# Upgrade jupyter notebook to 6.0.2 with conda

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda, anaconda3

I am trying to upgrade jupyter notebook using conda.

When I try `conda upgrade notebook`

I get

```
Updating notebook is constricted by

anaconda -> requires notebook==6.0.1=py37_0
```

The current version of notebook is 6.0.1

I also tried `conda install notebook=6.0.2`

This resulted in a very long output about conflicts. I can post that if needed. If these conflicts are the reason I cannot upgrade, how can I fix them automatically?

Here is the output of `jupyter notebook --version`

```
jupyter core     : 4.5.0
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.1
qtconsole        : 4.5.5
ipython          : 7.8.0
ipykernel        : 5.1.2
jupyter client   : 5.3.3
jupyter lab      : 1.1.4
nbconvert        : 5.6.0
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 4.4.0
traitlets        : 4.3.3
```

Comment: The reason is because you have `anaconda` (package) installed, which restricts package versions to keep some stability. If you don't need the specific fixes in the patch update, it's probably best not to update. If you insist on upgrading, please post the complete output of `conda install notebook=6.0.2` here to try and diagnose the base cause.

Comment: @darthbith Ah thanks. I was trying to update to 6.0.2 in order to get the command `jupyter notebook` to open a new browser tab automatically. I'm using WSL. Apparently you can do this by setting the option `use_redirect_file` to False, but that option isn't present in the jupyter config file until 6.0.2. This is kind of silly, so I guess I'll just wait on updating.

Comment: Hmm that seems like a very useful feature, I wonder why it's just a patch version bump? Well, in any case, I'm glad that helped :-)