# Why does `conda update jupyter` not upgrade to Jupyter Notebook 7.0+ on my macOS 14.0 system?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda, jupyter

According to https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/releases/tag/v7.0.6 Jupyter Notebook is now on version 7.0.6 and according to the **[documentation](https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/use/upgrade-notebook.html#upgrading-jupyter-notebook-using-anaconda)** I should be able to update to it via `conda update jupyter`. However, on my macOS 14.0 system (running on an M2 Max chip), running that command leaves me on notebook version 6.5.4.

What am I missing? Is there no stable release for Jupyter Notebooks higher than 6.5.4 out for macOS yet?

Comment: No, there is a stable release. You can see the link to the page with the info and the command over in my comment to a similar post four days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77287746/how-to-install-and-run-jupyter-notebook-7-using-conda#comment136254954_77287746). It may require a different command though and then see if it is possible on your system? Version 7+ is very different tech underlying it than 6.5.4 (or NbClassic), see links in the second half of my post for more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004).

Comment: Note over [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html#changelog) it says use `conda upgrade notebook`. I'm not sure why it isn't consistent in the Jupyter vs. Jupyter Notebook documentation. I do think the overarching 'Jupyter' documentation may get neglected more than the Jupyter Notebook documentation as Notebook 7+ is clearly discussed [in the Jupyter Notebook doucmentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), whereas the link in your post is back still mentioning 'IPython Notebook'.

Comment: Even after running `conda upgrade notebook`, I still get `notebook : 6.5.4` when I check `jupyter --version`.

Comment: That seems to align with what the other post said. I was waiting to hear back from that person before I suggested specifying the exact version in your conda command. I think it is 7.0.5 as of the other day. [This old comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63338854/upgrade-jupyter-notebook-to-6-0-2-with-conda#comment112018981_63338854) is about another version but is pertinent in regards to specifying the version. You'll also want to include the channel as in the link I pointed out in the comment over at the other similar post.  The hope is specifying may highlight the base cause.

Comment: Also, in your case it may be a channel thing? Maybe? See the discourse in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73415203/8508004) for maybe why I think that. I'd be more confident about this offering hope if it had worked for [Teun M. over in the similar post I mentioned already], but even including the channel had not gotten Teun version 7+; however, you mileage may vary. Also, I'd like to amend my previous comment with this:....More current comments about specifying versions is [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/issue-in-jupyter-notebook/21576/2?u=fomightez).

Comment: Please move things you try into the question body rather than in comments. Further, we need more details about the environment you are trying to manipulate. For example, what does `conda list '(jupyter|notebook)'` show? The `conda update` command does not guarantee to install the latest version, only the latest *compatible* version with the environment's current constraints. If you have over-specified other things in the environment, then it could prevent getting a version 7 installed. One can force Conda to explain by doing `conda install 'notebook>=7'`.

Comment: Cannot recreate. I had no trouble running `conda update -n jupyter notebook`, which led to install v7.0.6 of `notebook` and the `jupyter --version` reflects this.

Comment: @merv Not for me. Even after creating a new environment via `conda create --name jupyter`, activating it via `conda activate jupyter`, then running `conda install notebook` and finally checking the version via `jupyter --version`, I get as output `notebook: 6.5.4` (among other packages like `IPython: 8.15.0`, `jupyter_client: 7.4.9`, etc.

Comment: @merv Only by explicitly running `conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab=4.0.7 notebook=7.0.6` does it update to the specified versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By explicitly running `conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab=4.0.7 notebook=7.0.6` I managed to update to the latest version.