# Miniconda Jupyter notebook won't install

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda, jupyter, conda-forge

I cant install jupyter notebook in conda environment (miniconda). Instead of jupyter notebook, it installs the jupyterlab.

I tried this command.

`conda create --prefix ./env pandas numpy matplotlib scikit-learn jupyter`

And also tried to install notebook after creating and activating the environment with the conda-forge channel.

`conda install -c conda-forge notebook`

Can you tell me how can I install jupyter notebook. **Not the jupyterlab.**

Comment: See the comments below [the post titled 'Why does `conda update jupyter` not upgrade to Jupyter Notebook 7.0+ on my macOS 14.0 system?' here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77309960/why-does-conda-update-jupyter-not-upgrade-to-jupyter-notebook-7-0-on-my-macos#comment136460995_77309960). Some people found they needed to specify the exact version of Notebook 7+ when using `conda install` / `conda upgrade`. Maybe try that? You can see the current version (7.0.6) and versions available by looking at [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/notebook) ....

Comment: <continued> , in comparison to [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/releases). Keeping in mind it takes time for the conda-recipe to get made for the latest versions. The listing [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/notebook/files), linked to from the former link, can give you an idea of the specific versions available via conda-forge.