# Error in launching the jupyter notebook from anaconda

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, tornado, jupyter-lab

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sandh\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\sandh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 57, in 
raise ImportError(_("The Jupyter Notebook requires tornado >= 5.0, but you have %s") % tornado.version)
ImportError: The Jupyter Notebook requires tornado >= 5.0, but you have 4.5.3
```

How to solve that and where to get the required `tornado` version?

Comment: How are you launching Jupyter Notebook? Also, what have you tried so far to solve this? I recommend reading [ask] to improve your question.

Comment: You seem to be running an old version of a lot of things. Jupyter recently changed quite a bit. If you don't have a lot of environments at this point and a lot of other use of Anaconda, it may be easier to just uninistall Anacaonda and reinstall it to get the current best set of software it distrubutes. Otherwise, ...

Comment: <continued> based on [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#changelog), try `conda upgrade notebook`. Some people had reported needing to specify the 7+ version  when using`conda install` / `conda upgrade`, see my comments and reply comment below [the post titled 'Why does `conda update jupyter` not upgrade to Jupyter Notebook 7.0+ on my macOS 14.0 system?' here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77309960/why-does-conda-update-jupyter-not-upgrade-to-jupyter-notebook-7-0-on-my-macos#comment136460995_77309960).   Maybe try that if other routes seem to fail?